# Where do I get glfw.h file?

Tags: cocos2d-x, glfw, triangulation

I have downloaded poly2tri library for polygons triangulation, but this library has this include `#include <GL/glfw.h>`

Unfortunately, I don't have `glfw.h` file and even GL directory. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to download and install GLFW (http://www.glfw.org/)